# Apex class assistance

Tags: apex, class

We have a Trigger that calls out a Class everytime the Account Record Type is changed. I am new to this and we would like to make sure that the class will not delete anything or update anything but maintain whatever associated tsf_vod__c record is associated to the Account.

Here is the class: Thank you

```
@future
    public static void updateRecType (Set<String> acctIds) {    
        System.debug('acctIds with recType change ' + acctIds);

        // get TSF record types for update
        Map<String, ID> tsfRecTypes = new Map<String, ID>();
        List<ID> defRecType = new List<ID>();
        Boolean hasRecType = getTsfRecTypes(tsfRecTypes, defRecType);
        System.debug(tsfRecTypes);
        if (!hasRecType)
            return;
        String defRecTypeId = (defRecType.size() > 0) ? defRecType.get(0) : null;
        Map<ID, Account> accts = new Map<ID,Account>([Select Id,RecordType.Name From Account Where Id In :acctIds]);

        // update    
        for (List<TSF_vod__c> tsfs : [Select Id, Account_vod__c, 
                   YTD_Activity_vod__c, Territory_vod__c From TSF_vod__c where Account_vod__c in :acctIds] ) {
            List<TSF_vod__c> toDelete = new List<TSF_vod__c>();
            List<TSF_vod__c> toInsert = new List<TSF_vod__c>();
            List<TSF_vod__c> toUpdate = new List<TSF_vod__c>();
            for (TSF_vod__c tsf : tsfs) {
                Account acct = accts.get(tsf.Account_vod__c);
                if (acct != null) {
                    String tsfRecType = tsfRecTypes.get(acct.RecordType.Name);                
                    if (tsfRecType == null) {
                        if (defRecTypeId != null) {
                           System.debug('tsf ' + tsf.id + ' new(def) ' + defRecTypeId);
                           tsf.put('RecordTypeId', defRecTypeId); 
                           toUpdate.add(tsf);
                        }
                        else {
                          System.debug('tsf ' + tsf.id + ' is cleared');
                          // use delete + insert in order to clear RecordTypeId
                          toDelete.add(tsf);  
                          TSF_vod__c newTsf = new TSF_vod__c(YTD_Activity_vod__c = tsf.YTD_Activity_vod__c, Name = tsf.Territory_vod__c, 
                                  Account_vod__c = acct.Id, Territory_vod__c = tsf.Territory_vod__c);         
                          toInsert.add(newTsf);                       
                        }                         
                    }  
                    else {
                       System.debug('tsf ' + tsf.id + ' new ' + tsfRecType);
                       tsf.put('RecordTypeId', tsfRecType);
                       toUpdate.add(tsf);   
                    }                                   
                }  
            }

            if (toDelete.size() > 0) 
                delete toDelete;
            if (toInsert.size() > 0)
                insert toInsert;
            if (toUpdate.size() > 0) 
                update tsfs;
```

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Ming. Is there a specific problem that you're having? Where is your test class and what does it show? Also, I see that your code is incomplete, where is the remainder of it? Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ming - in addition to @crmprogdev suggestion, the best way to know if the class isn't inadvertently doing things you don't want is to write testmethods for various use cases. These test methods would have asserts to verify the database is in the expected state, - DML that should happen, happens; DML that shouldn't happen, doesn't happen

Comment: It is deleting a TSF record once the Account Record type is change. There is a trigger for any Account Record Type change and it calls this class. I would like to know how to stop the class from deleting TSF records. We don't want it to delete anything. Not really sure how I can do that.